# PHP: Making quotes on every word in string

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, str-replace

Beginner at PHP, looks fun. I have managed to put comma and "=>" everywhere i needed it to be but i need quotes around every word as well. I cant get my head around how to manage that part.

Im trying to build a nice array with key and value from string.

> Here is the begining of that string

```
$dummy = "ac whois.nic.ac 
          ae whois.aeda.net.ae 
          aero whois.aero 
          af whois.nic.af 
          ag whois.nic.ag 
          ...."
```

> What i need it to be is

```
"ac" => "whois.nic.ac", 
"ae" => "whois.aeda.net.ae", 
"aero" => "whois.aero", 
"af" => "whois.nic.af", 
"ag" => "whois.nic.ag",
```

> What i've got so far...

```
ac => whois.nic.ac, 
ae => whois.aeda.net.ae, 
aero => whois.aero, 
af => whois.nic.af, 
ag => whois.nic.ag,
```

*Create a comma on every "/n"*

```
$strg = preg_replace("/(?<![.])(?=[\n\r]|$)/", ",", $dummy);
```

*create "=>" on every space*

```
$strg = str_replace(' ', ' => ', $strg);
```

cheers..

Answer (score 0):

I would do this without using `preg_replace`:

```
$dummy = "ac whois.nic.ac 
      ae whois.aeda.net.ae 
      aero whois.aero 
      af whois.nic.af 
      ag whois.nic.ag 
      ....";
$lines = preg_split('[\r\n]+', $dummy, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$lines = array_filter(array_map(function($line){
    $line = trim($line);
    $words = explode(" ", $line, 2);
    if(count($words) !== 2) return null;
    return "\"$words[0]\" => \"$words[1]\",";
}));
$output = implode("\n", $lines); // or whatever EOL it was
```